# Implementing Pubsubhubbub in YouTube API project

Tags: youtube-api, publish-subscribe, youtube-data-api, websub

The docs for pubsubhubbub are not very good nor are they updated. Is there any good source to get help with setting it up? New to this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API(v3) has a documentation specific to "PubSubHubbub". You can refer to [this site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). From there, you will be redirected to an open, simple, web-scale decentralize pubsub protocol published by [github](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/).